# Can i work with SQLite and than switch to MySQL? Django

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite

I would like to start a project that would evantually require MySQL. However it is much easier for me not to use MySQL for now and instead to use SQLite. Is it possible to write the code using SQLite and at the end just switch to MySQL? How difficult is this?

Comment: Yes it will be fine. Once you feel good enough you can easily dump your content from one db and move it to another. Django provides some features for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546151/how-to-make-db-dumpfile-in-django for example. SQLite is pretty similar to postgres and mysql, there are some tweaks here and there but its mostly not a problem.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your project. If it is simple (few tables, not raw sql, django models only), then probably won't take much effort to move the code over to mysql. Otherwise it will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you just have to be clean in doing if not you will loose your data especially if its large.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah
You can convert to any sort of database like
(MySql/MongoDb/PostGrees)